# DRC head does not move

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Neither DRC tutorial seems to move the sensor head on the DRC robot
(control or animation). The other joints seem to move. The joint
that does not is neck_ay. Anyone else have the same problem?
Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/133/drc-head-does-not-move/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This problem seems to be due to the following line in the model.sdf file:

```
<limit effort="5" lower="0.785398" upper="0.785398" velocity="12"/>
```

which is due to this entry in drc_skeleton.cfg:

```
struct neck
    struct ay
        offset  = 0.011 0 0.49
        axis    = 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
        type    = revolute
        kin_min         = 0.785398163   # rad
        kin_max         = 0.785398163   # rad
        vel_min         = -12
        vel_max         = 12
        f_min           = -5
        f_max           = 5
```

setting a negative lower limit

```
  <limit effort="5" lower="-0.785398" upper="0.785398" velocity="12"/>
```

allows animation to work. control doesn't work, presumably because the gains or the torque
limit are bad.

---

Originally posted by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) with karma: 223 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-11-30**:
That vote should put you over the karma threshold for voting. Do what I did and use your limited votes on the best answers and question to help seed healthy community participation.